# Unable to work with Struts2 and REST Plugin

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I've been trying to work with the REST Plugin of Struts2 but was unable to make it work with a VERY simple project and following tutorials but I'm really unable to make it work.

I literally feel like I tried everything but nothing worked.
As I can't just post some code and have NO clue why my project is not working, here is my project attached (don't worry, it's only a base project with one class only, not a thousands of lines to debug).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wulbd7xmk5nwfl/Basic_Struts2_Mvn.zip

So the problem is that when I request /user, I get a 404 :/

Comment: Of course you can post code, and config; there's almost none to post.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have no controllers.

Your controllers need to be in `src/main/java`, not `src/main/resources`:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── resources
        │   ├── example
        │   │   └── UsersController.java  <-- Not a resource, but Java source.
        │   └── struts.xml
        └── webapp
            ├── WEB-INF
            │   └── web.xml
            └── index.jsp
```

There may be other issues as well.

Note that you don't need to explicitly include the convention plugin in your pom.

Comment: is convention plugin already part of the struts core?

Comment: @user962206 No, IIRC it's part of struts-plugins, as is the REST plugin.

Comment: well this is the default architecture I get with netbeans, I'll try it out, thanks ;)

Comment: @arthurquerou [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)